# how to set width for PdfPCell in ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

i want set width for PdfpCell in Table, i want design this

[image]
  i Write this code

```
  PdfPCell cell;
            PdfGrid tableHeader;
            PdfGrid tmpTable;
            PdfGrid table = new PdfGrid(numColumns: 1) { WidthPercentage = 100, RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR, ExtendLastRow = false };

            string imagepath2 = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "Header.JPG";
            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL };
            cell.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath2);
            table.AddCell(cell);


            tableHeader = new PdfGrid(numColumns: 10);
            tableHeader.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR;

            tmpTable = new PdfGrid(numColumns: 1);
            tmpTable.TotalWidth = 10f;
            tmpTable.LockedWidth = true;
            cell = new PdfPCell() {Rotation =-90,VerticalAlignment =Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment =Element.ALIGN_CENTER, BorderWidth = 1};
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("SER. No");

            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(tmpTable) { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            tmpTable = new PdfGrid(numColumns: 1);
            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0,  BorderWidthBottom = 1,VerticalAlignment =Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment =Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("TYPE OF SHIPPING");
            //
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("AWB / BL NO.");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(tmpTable) { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            tmpTable = new PdfGrid(numColumns: 1);
            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, BorderWidthBottom = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("ORDER NO.");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("COMPLEX NAME");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(tmpTable) { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            tmpTable = new PdfGrid(numColumns: 1);
            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, BorderWidthBottom = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("QTY.");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("G.W Kgs.");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(tmpTable) { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            tmpTable = new PdfGrid(numColumns: 1);
            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, BorderWidthBottom = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("DISCHARGE PPORT");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("DESTINATON");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(tmpTable) { BorderWidth = 1 };
            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            cell = new PdfPCell() { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("DESCRIPTION OF GOODS");

            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            tmpTable = new PdfGrid(numColumns: 1);
            cell = new PdfPCell() { Border = 0, BorderWidthBottom = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("LINE DOC. RECI. DATE");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) { Border = 0, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("OWNER DOC. RECI. DATE");
            tmpTable.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(tmpTable) { BorderWidth = 1 };
            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            cell = new PdfPCell() { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("CLEARANCE DATE");

            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            cell = new PdfPCell() { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("CUSTOM PERMIT NO.");

            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            cell = new PdfPCell() { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
            cell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process("DISPATCH DATE");
            tableHeader.AddCell(cell);

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            cell = new PdfPCell(tableHeader) { BorderWidth = 1, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };

            table.AddCell(cell);
            doc.Add(table);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            doc.Close();
```

but this code create this table
[image]

i want resize width SerNo column but

But I do not know how to resize the width of the cell, please help me.

Comment: Why do you use PdfGrid and not PdfPTable? It's no clear what exactly you want to do. There's a table then there's a tableHeader and they have no link. (???)

Comment: @ Nick : table Header is Nested tables, in this cell just RowNo and  want I am small and the width

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Why not use a `PdfPTable` object for this?
Create a fixed width table and use a float array to set the widths of the columns

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
table.TotalWidth = 500f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 60f, 60f, 30f, 50f, 80f, 50f, 50f, 50f, 50f };
table.SetWidths(widths);

addCell(table, "SER.\nNO.", 2);

addCell(table, "TYPE OF SHIPPING", 1);
addCell(table, "ORDER NO.", 1);
addCell(table, "QTY.", 1);
addCell(table, "DISCHARGE PPORT", 1);

addCell(table, "DESCRIPTION OF GOODS", 2);

addCell(table, "LINE DOC. RECL DATE", 1);

addCell(table, "CLEARANCE DATE", 2);
addCell(table, "CUSTOM PERMIT NO.", 2);
addCell(table, "DISPATCH DATE", 2);

addCell(table, "AWB/BL NO.", 1);
addCell(table, "COMPLEX NAME", 1);
addCell(table, "G. W. Kgs.", 1);
addCell(table, "DESTINATION", 1);
addCell(table, "OWNER DOC. RECL DATE", 1);

....

private static void addCell(PdfPTable table, string text, int rowspan)
{
    BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
    iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 6, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text, times));
    cell.Rowspan = rowspan;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    table.AddCell(cell);
}
```

have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables) too...

Comment: i've updated my question with the sample provided. It's all about setting the width on the table

Comment: I like this one, it's cleaner. You could also go further and make a sort of template row in a method. You'd call the method with something like `AddRow(PdfPTable _t, DataRow _dr, bool _head)`. From there all is easy.

Comment: @Nick.T: even better indeed, I've updated my code sample, but just for each of the cells

Comment: Can anyone please help how to set width of cell/column in .net?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
PdfPCell cell;
PdfPTable tableHeader;
PdfPTable tmpTable;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10) { WidthPercentage = 100, RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR, ExtendLastRow = false };

// row 1 / cell 1 (merge)
PdfPCell _c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SER. No")) { Rotation = -90, VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, BorderWidth = 1 };
_c.Rowspan = 2;

table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 2
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TYPE OF SHIPPING")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 3
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ORDER NO.")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 4
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("QTY.")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 5
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DISCHARGE PPORT")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 6 (merge)
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DESCRIPTION OF GOODS")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
_c.Rowspan = 2;
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 7
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("LINE DOC. RECI. DATE")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 8 (merge)
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OWNER DOC. RECI. DATE")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
_c.Rowspan = 2;
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 9 (merge)
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CLEARANCE DATE")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
_c.Rowspan = 2;
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 1 / cell 10 (merge)
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CUSTOM PERMIT NO.")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
_c.Rowspan = 2;
table.AddCell(_c);


// row 2 / cell 2
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("AWB / BL NO.")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 2 / cell 3
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("COMPLEX NAME")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 2 / cell 4
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("G.W Kgs.")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 2 / cell 5
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DESTINATON")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

// row 2 / cell 7
_c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OWNER DOC. RECI. DATE")) { VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
table.AddCell(_c);

_doc.Add(table);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
_doc.Close();
```

You might need to re-adjust slightly on the widths and borders but that is a one shot to do.

Answer (score 3):

try this code I think it is more optimal.

HeaderRow is used to repeat the header of the table for each new page automatically

```
        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 6, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10) { HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, WidthPercentage = 100, HeaderRows = 2 };
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 2f, 6f, 6f, 3f, 5f, 8f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SER.\nNO.", times)) { Rowspan = 2, GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TYPE OF SHIPPING", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ORDER NO.", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("QTY.", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DISCHARGE PPORT", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DESCRIPTION OF GOODS", times)) { Rowspan = 2, GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("LINE DOC. RECL DATE", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CLEARANCE DATE", times)) { Rowspan = 2, GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CUSTOM PERMIT NO.", times)) { Rowspan = 2, GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DISPATCH DATE", times)) { Rowspan = 2, GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("AWB/BL NO.", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("COMPLEX NAME", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("G. W. Kgs.", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DESTINATION", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OWNER DOC. RECL DATE", times)) { GrayFill = 0.95f });
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the widths:

```
float[] anchoDeColumnas= new float[] {10f, 20f, 30f, 10f};
```

Apply to the table:

```
table.setWidths(anchoDeColumnas);
```